# SerialPort.GetPortNames() returns incorrect port names

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, windows-10

While c# is not my primary programming language, I'm maintaining such a program for a couple of years now. This program connects to a device on a serial port and works from Windows XP up to 8.1. One specific "feature" is that it uses .NET Framework 2.0.

With some users upgrading to Windows 10 we've got complains that the program cannot detect/open the COM port of the device. We have confirmed this on our own test systems with clean Win10 installation.

It turns out that the function SerialPort.GetPortNames() returns incorrect port names and adds 'strange' characters after the port name.
For example:

- COM3吀
- COM3䡢
- COM3゠

Etc. When I refresh the list, every time another character (or two) shows up after the number.
The test code is super straightforward:

```
  string[] portNames = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
  log("Available ports:");
  foreach (string PortAvailable in portNames)
  {
    log(PortAvailable);
  }
```

Where the log function mearly adds a line to a standard TextBox on the form:

```
  txtLog.Text += Msg + Environment.NewLine;
```

This works in every other Windows version.
I've checked the registry and all looks fine there also.
Does anybody has an idea about this?

I'm suspecting that .NET Framework 2.0 is not 100% compatible anymore, although you can enable it in the Windows features and it seems that the program itself runs fine (besides my serial port problem). I'm a bit scared to upgrade to a newer .NET, let alone that we've VisualStudio 2008 for c# (max=.NET 3.5). Note that the program still needs to run on Windows XP also (POS version is still maintained by Microsoft).

ADDED:
I've "upgraded" a test program to .NET 3.5, and still having exactly the same issue.
Next step is to install a new VisualStudio (it appears that it is free nowadays?? Should I check for privacy settings in Studio also? ;-).

ADDED 2:
Installed VisualStudio 2015 and made multiple builds with different .NET framework versions. v2.0 and 3.5 still adding the strange character. But in v4.0 and up this issue seems te be solved! Now to get the original program compiled and working for the newer Framework.
But I find this issue really strange and would expect that this would hit more .NET functions and more programs.

Comment: i think it's about time to upgrade to .net 4 man, really, it's also about time to stop support for winxp, don't be that company that is still running win3.1
....... force your clients to upgrade, if they were running 7? ok, but xp? today? also, you do not have to force them, just provide the .net 4 installer with your next update

Comment: We're talking about retailers, using Windows XP POS which is still supported by Microsoft. And the current software of some will probably not even run on newer Windows version. Since we're supplying only a small addition to their system, we cannot force anybody :-( ... If MS supports .NET 3.5 on Win10 then they should fix the bugs.

Comment: You do have a point here but still. Eventually you will have to. I would suggest investing in a team to slowly upgrade your software to the new.net version. No need to rush it. But be prepared when the time comes

Comment: @JohnDemetriou - We have ;-) I've rebuild the project in VS2015 with .NET 4.0 and works (as you can read in the "added 2" part). However we don't like to have two code bases to maintain. So we'll keep 3.5 for now with the port name workaround (which works perfect) and suggest every XP customer to really upgrade asap. Also we're very reluctant when a new customer uses XP. But money is money :-D

Comment: I've reported this bug to Microsoft, and managed to track down at least some of the causes of it (at least for us and out product).  For more detail, see this forum thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a78b4668-ebb6-46aa-9985-ec41667abdde/ioportsserialportgetportnames-registrykeygetvalue-corruption-with-usbsersys-driver-on-windows?forum=netfxbcl  Short version is that it is the rewritten usbser.sys driver (used for CDC serial devices) on Windows 10 has a bug where .NET's GetPortNames() registry read gets corrupted data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen the strange characters too.  My solution is using Regular Expressions to filter out the number portion of the comm port name.

```
Dim ports As New Devices.Ports
For Each s As String In ports.SerialPortNames
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "\D*(\d+)\D*", "$1")
    Debug.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. So it really is a Microsoft bug, I'm curious what other .NET functions have a similar issue. The real sollution here would be they solving this, but lets not wait for this.
While using .NET Framework 4 probably would be the best solution, we have chosen to filter the port name. This way we can still serve Windows XP users and we don't have to test all details of the software against the new .NET version. So I set this answer as the solution for us.

Comment: The random garbage character is quite often another digit, so although this regex gets you most of the way there, its not completely reliable.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this exact same problem with USB CDC serial devices, handled by the new rewritten Windows 10 usbser.sys driver.

The garbage characters are often digits, so removing non-digits isn't a reliable way to work around it.  For my solution, look at my last post on this thread here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a78b4668-ebb6-46aa-9985-ec41667abdde/ioportsserialportgetportnames-registrykeygetvalue-corruption-with-usbsersys-driver-on-windows?forum=netfxbcl

..there is code there that'll go through the registry, find usbser ports, and return their unmangled names.  Beware that it doesn't return *all* serial ports, just ones provided by that driver.  The code works on Windows XP through to 10.

The underlying problem is that the usbser.sys driver creates a registry entry, and on .NET (at least up to 3.5) the GetPortNames() function tries to read those registry keys and gets corrupted data.  I've reported this to Microsoft, both via that forum (assuming they read it) and using the built-in Windows 10 beta error reporting tool.  Maybe one day there will be a fix.

Comment: Many thanks for the additional information, finding more details and reporting the bug. As far as I have seen, the garbage characters are mostly unicode glyphs. Running in the field for some time now at multiple locations without problems, so they also have non-digit chars. But I agree that it isn't a reliable way and will look into your msdn post.

Comment: I agree that its usually unicode characters, or Latin letters, but on my development machine I have been seeing digits fairly regularly (maybe 1 in 10 times!) -- I wasn't brave enough to ship our product with those sort of odds, which is why I focused on a more complicated but reliable solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you say the program works after enabling the windows feature:

.NET 2.0,3.0,3.5 isn't enabled by default on Windows 8/8.1/10. The files aren't stored on the install media/wim.

It can be enabled with the DISM command from windows update or a local source.

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it. The program does not work at all without .NET 2.0, which is obvious. The setup does not let us install it at all.
With .NET 2.0 the function returns incorrect values, as indicated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

check this out: http://forums.radioreference.com/uniden-tech-support/317887-windows-10-uniden-usb-driver-5.html
For a work around to fix the Win 10 serial port not working caused by strange characters after the port name.

1. Go in to the Registry with regedit.exe.
2. Navigate to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALC OMM"
3. Make note of the comm port name.
4. Append a "0" or any character to the comm port name.
5. Change the comm port name back to what it was in step 3.

It worked for me.
Baldur

Comment: Thanks for the input, it sure is a solution for an enduser with a little registry experience (as most stackoverflow visitors probably are ;-). But as a software supplier we cannot ask our users to hack their settings. I also assume that it is temporarily where plugging in new devices (or sometimes using another port) gives the corrupt portnames again. MS should fix this, but for now the accepted solution has proven itself in the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        for (int i = 0; i<ports.Length;i++)
        {
            string mystr = ports[i];
            if (((mystr[mystr.Length-1]) >= 0x30) & ((mystr[mystr.Length-1]) <= 0x39))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                mystr = mystr.Remove(mystr.Length-1);
            }
            ports[i] = mystr;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to add an explanation to your answer proposal.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is basically the same as the Regex from the accepted answer, but more code and less performance. So I cannot see any advantage here.