# Java list returns weird values (string)

Tags: java, list, listview, serial-communication

I'm using `JSerial` for Serial communications. `JSerial` offers a method to get a list of available ports. When im using this method it returns the `COM` ports as it is supposed to be as a List. But I have some Trouble with the return values. If I use the debugger everything is fine, return values look like they should `"COM1"`. But when I run the project the return values are some sort of compromised. Outputs look like this **COM110000-00൥帿À阀COM16000-000൫帿À耀fF1CE}**

The problem is that the values differ from Debugging and runtime.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

[Correct values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ebph.png)

[Incorrect values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zutxp.png)

Comment: Sounds like it's probably more to do with JSerial than lists. I suggest you log the values in the console, including the length of each string. See how that changes between debug and non-debug.

Comment: I just did that. In debug mode everything is fine, all strings contain the correct or expected output and length, whilst at runtime they have a length up to 36.. Must be a problem with JSerial but I dont understand how the debug mode can affect it that way..

Comment: Right. Now would be a good time to create a [mcve] - just a console app that lists the values - and give details of how you're running it in the debugger and not. That way others can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What List view do you use to display the data in the non-debug environment? It looks like the String is converted to a C character array without 0-terminating it.

Comment: Im using the JavaFX ListView shipped with NetBeans. But also "System.out.println()" produces the same "wrong" output as the binding to the listview does. In debug mode both, console output also as the listview are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but anyway interesting.

For me it looks more like a general problem. Either with the [JNA library](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) or with Windows (found something similar at [SerialPort.GetPortNames() returns incorrect port names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040209/serialport-getportnames-returns-incorrect-port-names))

Using plain JNA (tested with version 4.2.2 and 4.4.0)

```
Advapi32Util.registryGetValues(
        WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM")
        .entrySet()
        .forEach(
                e -> System.out.printf(
                        "k: %s  v: %s%n",
                        e.getKey(),
                        e.getValue()
                )
        );
```

also returns COM port names with some garbage characters at the end. Those are even changing between several executions.

```
// an execution
k: CcmPort1  v: COM1ꭲ峔K谀

// another execution
k: CcmPort1  v: COM1ǖ㭪谀
```

Why it's ok in debug mode in your IDE? If it's always the case, then maybe there are other libraries/DLLs in the path or you are always lucky.

**btw.** Powershell retrieve the correct names.

```
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
```